# Is there a way to press a button 1000times a second in AHk

Tags: autohotkey

Hi i need to find out how to press a button for example b 1000times or more in a second
can someone help me please thank you.

Comment: Even if you find a way to do this, the software that has to respond to it is unlikely to cope.

Answer (score 0):

This will make your script send keys as fast as it can; use with caution. Hold F1 to spam.

```
SetBatchLines, -1
#KeyHistory 0
ListLines, Off
SetKeyDelay, -1
; Windows Explorer ignores SendInput's simulation of certain navigational hotkeys such as Alt + ←
SendMode Input

F1::
    while GetKeyState("F1", "P")
    {
        Send, A
    }
return
```